# Is it possible to buy an iPhone from Apple without a plan?

Tags: iphone, apple-store

I'm really interested in purchasing an iPhone, but I'm usually in a Wi-Fi area, so I don't see a reason to waste money on a plan I don't need. Is there any way I can buy an iPhone **through Apple** without signing up for a service plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy a contract-free iPhone directly from Apple. Just click on "Or get an iPhone unlocked and contract-free":

[image]

Comment: Make sure you read the warning below, this phone (in the US) only works with AT&T (unless you have another carrier in your area), but won't work with verizon or sprint.

Comment: It will also work with T-Mobile although you will only get 2G data in most areas if you get a plan with cellular data. It also works with 3rd party carriers that use the AT&T or T-Mobile network.